# Manage custom history

Tags: reactjs, browser, react-router, back-button

Imagine we have **2 type of flows** in the app:

1. **PageA** → WizardStep1 → WizardStep2 → WizardStep3 → **PageB**
2. PageC → **PageD** → WizardStep1 → WizardStep2 → **PageD**

In the 1st flow we redirect user to different page.
Notice - in the 2nd flow we come back to original page PageD.

Every page and wizard step is different component and has **it's own URL**.
Naturally when we click browser back button we navigate back in history of the browser.

The requirements are:

- When we click back on any wizard step we go one step back - that's
  normal behavior (e.g. from WizardStep3 back to WizardStep2)
- But once
  wizard is completed, we cannot go back to wizard

Let me try to explain it differently:

```
1. PageA → [ WizardStep1 → WizardStep2 → WizardStep3 ] → PageB
```

**everything in the square bracket is the process** and once we finished with it, we cannot go back to that process again, we should skip it.
But if we didn't complete wizard we can go back.

For the flow 2 it's more like this

```
2. PageC → PageD <-> [ WizardStep1 → WizardStep2 ]
```

**The problem**

User on PageB clicks browser back and expect to see PageA, but we go to previous step WizardStep3 (for the flow 1)

User on PageD after wizard completion click back and expect to see PageC, but we go back to wizard.

**My initial thoughts**

By the way, I am using Page A,B,C,D. To make it more real, imagine that flow 1 is user is filling Application with many forms split by steps. Once it's done, you cannot go back and change data. PageA could be the page where wizard was initiated.
For flow 2 - imagine Profile editing, where PageD is Profile and PageC is any previous page.

I know that in browser we cannot remove history, but we can count step and  use goBack(-COUNT). For the flow 2 it can work, not for flow 1.
So maybe we maintain our own history and we pop and push URLs there and every time user clicks browser back we use our custom history and always use history.push for the browser, but I am not sure it windown.onpopstate is reliable enough.

Answer (score 1):

I cant add comments so i answer.

I havent tested this but apparently React Router has a history.go(n) method you can use to go back n times (for example -3)

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/history.md

I hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion, but this is not exactly what I am looking for,
This will work only for the flow 2, because we return to PageD.

In flow 1 - we cannot go back, we need to go the different page.

Comment: The thing is that hitting back and going two-three pages in time could make sense to me, but going to a complete different page I have never visited sounds weird. Could you control this with a cookie so in case the user goes back you can see the wizard was completed and redirect? Or maybe make sure the user goes to that page by directly redirecting when its done?